# browser resize div collapse at min-width

Tags: html, css

Can you in css target a div that has a min-width attribute so when the browser is resized and the div is at min-width value the div will collapse then it goes to 100% width, how do you do it?

```
div {min-width:300px; background-color:red; max-width:600px; height:300px}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and ( max-width:1024px) {
    div {
        width:100%
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the selector to

```
div[style*="min-width"] {
    width:100%;
}
```

However this will work only if this style is embedded into the div style attribute.
I think it would be better if you add those divs a class and then the selector will be

```
div.myclass {
    width:100%;
}
```

Which is much more reliable in my opinion.

Comment: So basically I want to have 3 types of classes that are desktop tablet and mobile and they would have different min-width: so when the browser resizes they collpase when they are at the min-width value could you make me up a jsFiddle with example like what I explained or something similar this is for a css grid

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz7QD/   I changed the values so it will work in a small area.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at bootstrap that is already built for these sort of things.